# Unable to push Helm Chart to Google Cloud Artifact Registry using OCI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, helm3

I'm trying to push a helm chart to Google Cloud ***OCI*** registry (Artifact Registry) but I get forbidden error:

`helm push testapp-1.0.0.tgz oci://europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/project-id/my-artifact-registry/`

> Error: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token:
> unexpected status: 403 Forbidden

It seems that I'm authenticated ok since when I do try to push it but without **"oci://"** it works fine:

`helm chart push europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/project-id/my-artifact-registry/charts/testapp:1.0.0`

> The push refers to repository [europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/..]
> ref: europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/...
> digest: 2757354aef8af2db48261d52c17c0df35a99d6fccaf016b0e67e167c391b69c7
> size:3.9 KiB 
> name:    testapp 
> version: 1.0.0
> 1.0.0: pushed to remote (1 layer, 3.9 KiB total)

I logged in to the helm registry using service account json key, using below command:

`helm registry login -u _json_key_base64 --password <base_64_key> https://europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev`

and this service-account has below roles:

> roles/artifactregistry.admin
> roles/artifactregistry.repoAdmin
> roles/artifactregistry.writer
> roles/container.developer
> roles/storage.admin
> roles/storage.objectViewer

Is there any specific permission needs to be enabled in GCP to use "OCI" protocol?

or any service need to be enabled?

or any different authentication required?

I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/helm/manage-charts) but with no success

Answer (score 2):

its funny, but this is not the first time it happens to me... once I submit the question to Stackoverflow, something hits me and I'm able to find the problem with my issue!!

Anyway, the problem is basically with the authentication, where the URL to login to should be in the format of:

`https://LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT/REPOSITORY`

like this:

```
helm registry login -u _json_key_base64 --password <base_64_key> \
   https://europe-north1-docker.pkg.dev/project-id/my-artifact-registry
```

Comment: Do you have to run this command before you do helm push? I got the same error and the doc doesn't have anything related to helm registry login

Comment: @TJLiu yes you do need to login if your helm registry is secured

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue but using Cloudbuild.
I am glad if this snippet of code can help someone.

```
steps:
  - name: 'alpine/helm:3.9.1'
    id: 'helm package'
    args: ['package', '.']
  - name: 'alpine/helm:3.9.1'
    id: 'helm push'
    env:
      - 'HELM_REGISTRY_CONFIG=../builder/home/.docker/config.json'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        helm push --debug mylibchart-*.tgz oci://europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/helm-registry
```

Basically in the step where we want to push our *.tgz., we need to set the env **HELM_REGISTRY_CONFIG** equal to the default path of the docker config.json.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda stupid but I was transitioning from container registry to the artifact registry and I forgot to give my service account permissions for the artifact registry [image] which resulted in this exact error.